# How to get access token in Google Cloud Function for using Google API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, bearer-token

I want to use **google cloud functions** to handle all search requests from user clients (app).

The scenario is like different users do searches on their applications and all those search requests would be sent to the **cloud function** first, then the cloud function does the actual search with **google retail API**, and then send back results to users after several modifications.

Google retail API needs **OAuth2** as authentication in its request header, this confused me.

When I use PostMan to do the Oauth2, it redirects me to a screen to do authentication, but it is impossible to do that in a cloud function.

After doing some research, I know that a service account might fit my need, but I do not know to do it and stuck here for nearly 2 days.

I want to know how to do this **authentication** in the google cloud function to **generate  OAuth2 token** for accessing google retail API.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically)?

Answer (score 0):

I am also stuck with this and the documents are not clear to me. I do use firebase push notifications and that works fine. There are so many 'tokens' you cant easily tell which one should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below Might be of help. I literally discovered this by accident when going through firebase security checklist.

Basically it seems you need googlecloud SDK and you need to send a command to the SDK console to print the access token.

Here's the documentation webpage describing it. I am not sure if it will be of help but it hits most of the points you are asking (authentication & access token):

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-access-token